# Brackets in the statement. How does it work?

Tags: python, brackets

I'm not `Python` developer, but I need to translate a script from that language into `C#`. So far so good, but... What does this statement do? I tried to look for it in the internet, but nothing found.

```
self.bands = 5
self.ci = [0] * self.bands
```

Could any1 describe what happens here?
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It multiplies the list of single zero five times:

```
self.ci = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Could be written as:

```
self.ci = []
for i in xrange(self.bands):
    self.ci.append(0)
```

Comment: @Nickon There's an important gotcha you should be aware of when using this feature. The items in the resulting list are not *copies* of the original item in brackets. They're *references* to it. So if the item was mutable (say, a `list`) instead of your immutable `0`, you will get a list of five references to that *same* object. This is pretty much always not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the description of that issue:)

Answer (score 1):

It multiplies a list of the integer 0 by `self.bands`, which will create a list of length `self.bands`, containing a bunch of repeated 0s.

This is the idiomatic way of creating a repeated sequence in Python.

You can also use it for strings, which are sequences:

```
>>> print "!" * 10
!!!!!!!!!!
```